# v.generalize creates SHP instead of GPKG

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to use generalize.smooth, but the time I try to save in GPKG (GeoPackages) it always saves in SHP.
The reason for saving in GPKG is that the file has more than 5GB and is impossible to save in shape.
Generalize has the save option in GPKG, but the output is always in SHP.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I'm not sure whether this is a known issue, but we'll need more details about your process, to work from there. At first glance, a 5GB shapefile seems really huge!

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I must work with this size. That's why I use GPKG.

The error is simple ... I request that Generalize soften and save in GPKG, but it ends up saving in SHP. SHP can not handle data volume, but GPKG does.

Comment: I see this happening in QGIS 2.18.13 too - It looks like [it might be related to to this recently reported issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17614).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in the current developer version: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17614